# Question on probability...

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Five persons A, B, C, D, E throw a dice in the order named until one of them throws the number one: find their relative chances of winning supposing the throws to continue till one appear.

MY APPROACH: I made five cases that
(1) A throws one first
(2) B throws one and A doesn't
.
.
.
(5) E throws one and none four throws one before A does.

Now can anyone explain me how to solve further.

Comment: It is uncommon to refer to a result of a $1$ on a die as an "ace."  To avoid confusion, I suggest renaming it as a "one."  Now... suppose that $A$ begins the game and wins with probability $p$.  We have $p = \frac{1}{6}+\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^5p$.  Do you see why?  Armed with this knowledge, can you find $p$?  Can you then find the probability that $B$ wins using a similar method?

Comment: This is a legitimate way to start, though there are others. There's more than one way to continue. Would you prefer an infinite series or conditional probability?

Comment: @JMoravitz i think there should be multiplication instead of addition. And why it is power 5 it should be 4.

Comment: @UtsavDesai no., it is correct as written.  Player $A$ wins when the first thing he rolls is a $1$ **or** (*so we add*) when $A$ doesn't roll a $1$, $B$ doesn't roll a $1$, and so on, $E$ doesn't roll a $1$ (*for a total of five failed rolls, not four*) after which $A$ wins somehow either immediately or further in the future, and we are effectively back at our starting point, and $A$ wins from a starting point occurs with probability $p$.  Yes, we are using $p$ in the formula to find $p$, that is okay.

Comment: This could just as easily have been written using infinite series as $p = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{6}\cdot \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{5k}$ which will give the same result as before but requires knowledge of how to compute an infinite geometric series, something that the other explanation doesn't require.

Comment: Ok,... So what will be the final answer.   Also I don't know how you find that infinite series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining comments:

Let $p$ be the probability that $A$ wins.

Now... note that $A$ will win either when his first roll is a $1$ which occurs with probability $\frac{1}{6}$ or when all five players fail on their first roll and $A$ wins at some point from then on, the five player all failing their first rolls occurring with probability $\frac{5}{6}$ each and $A$ winning from that point on given that we have reached this state in the game which occurs with probability $p$ for a combined probability of $\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^5p$.

This gives us the equation:

$$p = \frac{1}{6}+\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^5p$$

Solving this, we get:

$$p = \frac{1296}{4651}$$

---

Alternatively, we could have described this with an infinite sum.  $A$ will win when he throws a $1$, or five failed rolls occur in a row followed by $A$ rolling a $1$, or $10$ failed rolls occur in a row followed by $A$ rolling a $1$, or so on so forth, covering all possibilities ranging over all multiples of five number of failed rolls.

We get as a result the following summation:

$$p = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{6}\cdot \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{5k}$$

Rearranging, we have:

$$p = \frac{1}{6}\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{5^5}{6^5}\right)^k\right)$$

Using what we know about geometric series, that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty x^k = \frac{1}{1-x}$, we have:

$$p = \frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{5^5}{6^5}} = \frac{1296}{4651}$$

---

We can similarly approach for the other players using either approach.

It is more correct and useful to say that $p$ is the probability that the player whose current turn it is will eventually win.

As such, we see that the probability that $B$ wins will be $\frac{5}{6}p$, that $C$ wins is $\frac{5^2}{6^2}p$ and so on...

Alternatively, we could have seen the probability $B$ wins as being $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{5}{6}\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{5k}$ which gives the same result.

It is worth verifying that the sum of the probabilities that $A,B,C,D,E$ win respectively will add up to $p+\frac{5}{6}p+\dots+\frac{5^4}{6^4}p$ which does indeed add up to $1$ as expected.